# Is there a German word for “analytics”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

The term *analytics* (as in *Google Analytics*, etc.) isn't a well-defined term but it’s understood especially in the context of web and technology.

Translating the term to German yields things like *Analyse* and *Analytik,* which even to a native speaker lose most of the implicit connotation to tracking user behavior. Dict.cc also suggests *Web-Controlling* which is essentially replacing one English term with another one.

So what would be the most equivalent word for *analytics* in German?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well analyse per se is not really specific. Of course, German offers you the possibility to create a compound word for a more accurate description. Since you mentioned tracking user behaviour, I'd go with

> Benutzerverhaltensanalyse

[Verhaltensanalyse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verhaltensanalyse) alone is already a common term to describe the behavioural analysis. Combining this with Benutzer (user) annotates the specific group whose behaviour you want to analyse.

Comment: Verhaltensanalyse is not what OP was looking for. Analytics is far more specific.

Comment: @bukwyrm "Analytics"  is "far more specific" than "analysis of user behavior"? Certainly not. It is something *different*: The *tools* of analysis as opposed to the analysis itself, not only targeting users but e.g. the website as well. But already the second example in [M-W's entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analytics) is doubtful: "Louisville and others will benefit from a data analytics program that can calculate which doctors are prescribing the most pain pills". Isn't that an *analysis* program? Doesn't sound as fancy... Excel could do it.

Comment: Verhaltensanalyse covers a wide swath of possible subjects, of which Analytics could be one. That one could well do Analytics with Excel (and some do) is immaterial.

Comment: @bukwyrm Sorry, calling "analytics" specific is just wrong. Plain "analysis" is already a meta term (a procedure that can be applied to arbitrary phenomena), and "analytics" is meta-meta because it means unspecified tools to perform arbitrary analyses of arbitrary subjects. Only the "web" context gives us a hint what it is all about at all. Sure, "Verhaltensanalyse" can mean different things in different contexts as well, but far more subject-bound. If we grant it the benefit of the same context we apply to "analytics" it's clearly more specific -- perhaps too specfic.

Comment: "... if we grant it the benefit of the same context..." - that is my point: 'Analytics' is web-analytics by default, while Verhaltensanalyse has no default of subject matter

Comment: I like to point out that I didn't recommend Verhaltensanalyse. I agree that Verhaltensanalyse alone is still unspecific. That's why I added Benutzer to it. That removes the ambiguity.

Comment: @bukwyrm What makes you assume that " 'Analytics' is web-analytics by default"? See [M-W:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analytics) "First Known Use of analytics circa 1590". That's perhaps spider-web analytics by default ;-).

Comment: Amazing how German works as a programming language!

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using *Webanalyse* or *Web-Analyse*. This is commonly used and in my opinion represents best what *Analytics* means.

Comment: Wikipedia offers a few alternatives: Web Analytics (auch Clickstream-Analyse, Datenverkehrsanalyse, Traffic-Analyse, Web-Analyse, Web-Controlling, Webtracking)

Answer (score 7):

Looking for a *proper* (whatever that shall mean) German word for *Analytics* is ignoring the reality of spoken language: Some loan words cannot fully be translated, since part of the meaning is transported by the mere fact that a loan word is used: The loan word is marking the social and pragmatic context.

Due to American cultural dominance in that field, internet technology is full of english words. Translating them into German would erase the domain of *internet* from their meaning: You would not expect a word like *Nutzungsbetrachtung*, *Nutzerverfolgung* or *Nutzeranalyse* to be used in the semantic field of *internet*, and so you would probably not understand it, even if any of those words was a perfect literal translation of *Analytics* (which none of them is, by the way).

The proper German word for *Analytics* is *Analytics*.

Comment: Thank you for (at least) considering *Nutzungsbetrachtung*, even though ex negativo. It is, still, the first use of that word outside its original egg shell, and I am looking positively forward to seeing it eventually fly.

Comment: WOT? "The history of German language is full of" *thousands of successful attempts to do that!* You might scoff at an author creating *Nutzungsbetrachtung*, now. But how would you have reacted to Luther? You either phrase this quite unluckily (and lead me to misunderstanding), or you are *completely* wrong on this. Und zwar mit aemulatio ignis, oder doch besser Feuereifer?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach   I never would. You are the involuntary godfather of my  new word's future success. I owe you much.

Comment: Die Umwelt der Schreckensherrschaft war der Terror des Mileus, schreibe ich mal so vom Okzident ins Abendland. Aber meine superstitio in Lehnübertragungen ist auch nur Aberglaube, der in Christians Ansatz weniger eine avant garde als eine Vorhut sieht. Ist ein homme d'affaire denn nicht Geschäftsmann geworden, der seinen parapluie weder gegen einen umbrella noch eine Regenschirm tauscht? Solche Wörter kommen und gehen, aber Nuancen und Feinheiten dieser Kleinodien fehlen manchmal wie automobile im Kraftwagen? So wandelt sich exemplum zum Beispiel.

Comment: @LangLangC OK, du hast mich überzeugt. Ich muss das zurücknehmen und schwächer formulieren. Mein Eindruck stammte von einem Wörterbuch aus der Mitte des 19 Jhds, das solche Empfehlungen abgegen hatte, wie Christian Geiselmann es hier tut. Da waren alle Alternativen ziemlicher Unfug und wurden auch wirklich nicht übernommen. Aber die Generalsaussage, die ich hier getroffen habe, ist falsch. Danke für die Kritik!

Comment: Man kann eben dicke Bücher vollschreiben mit gescheiterten und dadurch lustigen Versuchen (Zwischennetz statt Internet?), und umgekehrt sind genauso fette Schwarten gefüllt mit Wörtern, die so unauffällig und gewohnt daher kommen… Tollpatsch und Großvater, ist beides ja *so* deutsch, man will kaum glauben dass Ungarn und Franzosen das mehr oder weniger exportiert haben.

Comment: @LangLangC Ja, aber Tollpatsch ist ja nun ein Beispiel für ein nicht übersetztes Lehnwort. Das Wörterbuch, das ich meinte, war übrigens nicht als Sammlung gescheiterter Versuche angelegt, sondern ganz ernsthaft ein sprachhygienischer Versuch.

Comment: Persönlich war ich bei Tollpatsch auf germanische Onomatopoesie geeicht. Und das ist dann doch *immer* sehr angestrengt? Ist der Titel noch geläufig? Ich lese sowas tatsächlich gerne und mit Gewinn, auch wenn nur ein Bruchteil darin verwendbar, reanimierbar, ist. Obwohl, die Sammlung 'Unnützes Wissen' ist auch noch unvollständig ;)

Answer (score 5):

> The term analytics (as in Google Analytics, etc.) isn't a well-defined term but it’s understood especially in the context of web and technology.

You're starting your question with a false premise. I'm working in the data science field and here "analytics" is not at all commonly referring to user behaviour. That's only a part of it. You should use "web analytics" to make it clear for a broader audience.

> Translating the term to German yields things like Analyse and Analytik, which even to a native speaker lose most of the implicit connotation to tracking user behavior.

When translating IT terms many words lose their IT context. For example we say "Big Data" for the specific technology not "große Daten(mengen)". Other examples without German equivalent are "Machine Learning" or "Overfitting". While you could translate them literally, nobody would understand what you're talking about.

Thus I recommend to stick to the English term.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Nutzeranalyse ('analytics' regarding the user/-s) or Nutzungsanalyse ('analytics' regarding the use), equally valid are Benutzeranalyse and Benutzungsanalyse (with the same implied specifics)

For both, use is often interchangeable, as the meanings largely overlap.

https://saar.infowiss.net/projekte/ident/themen/benutz_forsch/kap1/

Comment: The same terms could conceivably used in English as well ("use[r] analysis"). Not least "analytics" is a term that is used rather incorrectly in an attempt to sound more important; much like "methodology" instead of method, or "technology" instead of technique. Or "analogy" instead of... ah well.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Is this a criticismy :-) of my translation?  I just wanted to convey that both terms (and their Be-prefix twins) refine 'analytics in a specific direction. I'll rephrase.

Comment: No, on the contrary: *Analyse* is better, and *analysis* would be better in English as well.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Ah, fundamental criticism. Well, we are d'accord on that front.

Answer (score 3):

> **Q** The term *analytics* (as in *Google Analytics*, etc.) isn't a well-defined term but it’s understood especially in the context of web and technology.

This description is only partially correct. The term 'analytics' itself might be understood 'well' and 'widely', even in tech-circles, but the negative aspects inherent to the application of this technology or often not, and not even in tech circles.

> [Analyse](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Analyse) f. ‘Auflösung, Zergliederung, Untersuchung’,

and the derivative of the equally Greek to me *Analytik* might be seen as expressing the desire to systematically collect, describe and understand data.

But for the intent of expressing the less desirable consequences attached to it, a trade name like *Google-Analytics* has to be seen as a euphemism.

To avoid or even counteract the euphemistic part, you might have to choose a word that better encompasses those parts of the possible meanings you think important:

*[Spähsoftware](https://www.dwds.de/?q=Sp%C3%A4hsoftware&from=wb)*, *Nutzerverhaltensspeicherungsverfahren*, *Überwachungssoftware* come to mind, but Wikipedia seems to prefer

***[Nutzerverfolgung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutzerverfolgung)***

as the most general term.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in a comment, [Merriam-Webster suggests](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analytics) that analytics is the *method* of analysis. That's why I would suggest that *analytics* is Google's term for their analysis tools, or **Analysewerkzeuge**. Of course the usual focus is on users because websites are used to interact with them. But I would be surprised if analytics didn't also provide ways to measure the technical aspects of a website, like retrieval times, time to page complete, server load etc. But it was hard to find out *what analytics specifically offers.* See my rant below which is quite on topic here because it is about web user experience, and language in the context of <strike>advertising</strike> marketing.

---

<rant> I just spent 10 minutes of my life trying to find out what specific functionality *analytics* provides. I started by googling "google analytics". The featured first hit first asks me to sign into google (!? why?) and then gets me to a page with minimal text and three icons. **The first icon asks me to sign up for analytics.** (Sorry, what?? Ah, that's why the wanted me to log in!) That's after just three words of explanation, "Analyze your site's traffic", in a headline. OK, so I click "Analytics home" at the bottom. There's a page consisting of — headlines above paragraphs of literally a single sentence each. Money quote: "Build a complete picture". You wish! Big emphasis is on the integration with the other google services and tools. Ah, on the bottom of this page full of fluff is a section "Resources" with a link to "product overview analytics". The click on "Read more" leads to another picture-heavy page with not much text, and all of it fluff. Money quote: **"With Google Analytics, you can uncover the insights that drive real results."** No shit, Sherlock! I feel like conversing with a Flat Earther for an hour or two: It's exhausting because you try to take them seriously but that brings you down to their level; it drains your intellectual capacity. I stop my research here, not least because I fear for my sanity. **It's all advertising, no hard facts whatsoever.**

Actually, I'm being unfair to that conversation partner, provided they act in good faith: Because google has an obvious agenda. They want to get a foot in the door of your website; they want your data. They aren't even hiding it. They aren't even telling you what they'll do on your site. I almost feel I should give up from exhaustion and just sign up so that they finally tell me.

Angesichts dieser Erfahrung könnte man "Google Analytics" auch einfach mit

**Werbe-Kraken-Daten-Haken**

übersetzen.</rant>

Comment: You should probably remove the rant part, as it is not related to the language question asked. The whole point of all analytics is to get hold of user data. In doing so there is no essential difference between Google, Facebook, Amazon, or whoever.

Comment: @Takkat The rant is important because it shows that it is hard to find out what analytics does, beyond "uncover the insights that drive real results". (That phrase  literally makes me sick in my stomach.) Since the proper term (in German or any language) hopefully heavily depends on what anaytics really *is and does*, that experience is entirely on topic in order to find a good German word for it. Like *Werbe-Daten-Kraken-Haken.* (And yes of course, that term is entirely applicable to the analysis tools of other web companies as well.)

Comment: The rant would of course be needed if we had been asked for a derogatory term but the question reads different. It would be answered nicely in your first paragraph but not in your second.

Answer (score 0):

Nach Lektüre der allesamt klugen bisherigen Beiträge und angesichts des daraus erhellenden Mangels eines eigentlichen deutschen Worts für *user analytics* (speziell im Kontext des Web-Publizierens) schlage ich hiermit vor:

> Nutzungsbetrachtung

Ich weiß, das Wort ist neu. Aber jedes Wort war einmal neu, und auch Zwerge haben klein angefangen.

Hier meine Gründe für genau diese Wahl:

Nutzung, nicht Nutzer: Es geht nicht um die Nutzer; es geht um die Art, wie die Nutzer die Website nutzen. Im Zentrum steht also die Nutzung.

Betrachtung: Ich denke, das ist ein gutes Wort für *Analyse*. Man könnte auch *Untersuchung* sagen, aber *Nutzungsuntersuchung* ist mit seinen vielen u schon etwas eintönig (und man kriegt beim Sprechen einen Krampf in den Lippen). Betrachtung bringt mehr Abwechslung bei den Vokalen. *Betrachtung* sei hier verstanden als die sehr genaue (eben: analytische) Form des Hinsehens.

Comment: Es bringt, denke ich, eher wenig, hier Neologismen vorzuschlagen. Wir sollten hier Empfehlungen geben, und nicht versuchen, die Sprache zu verändern. Dazu haben wir nämlich viel zu wenig Einfluss, und wir sollten gar nicht erst die Illusion erwecken. Das Feld ist so von Anglizismen geprägt - auch weil viele Internet-Firmen international besetzt sind - dass es die Realität der gesprochenen Sprache hart ignoriert, wenn man versucht, diese durch hausgemachte Neuschöpfungen zu ersetzen. Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ach was, immer her mit den neuen Wörtern! Und: Du ignorierst doch hier hart die Realität von Christian's gesprochener (naja, geschriebener) Sprache. (Nur am Rande: Allgemein gesprochen denke ich, dass die Welt ein besserer Ort wäre, wenn sich vor dreißig Jahren alle auf Englisch und 7-Bit-ASCII geeinigt hätten. Ohne Scheiß. Aber ob sie auch ein *schönerer* Ort wäre?)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Ich habe gar nichts gegen neue Wörter. Aber das hier ist ein Forum, in dem wir Leuten helfen wollen, Sprache zu verwenden. Und da ist das eben fehl am Platze, weil es niemandem weiterhilft, wenn man dieses Wort verwendet.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  Wir hätten keinen Einfluss auf den Sprachwandel? Wer sonst, wenn nicht wir, die Sprecher? Warte nur, du Zauderseele, bis sich meine schöne *Nutzungsbetrachtung* erst durchgesetzt hat! (Recht hast du natürich damit, dass Neuschöpfungen dem Frager mit seiner ursprünglichen Intention nicht weiterhelfen.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich bewerte hier eigentlich nur, wie hilfreich ich die Antwort auf eine Frage finde. Was sollte man hier sonst bewerten? Siehe auch mein Profil: _Please don't take up- or downvotes personally. When I believe, users shall read or consider an answer, I upvote it. When I believe an answer is wrong or misleading and readers should better not read it, i downvote it. It's about your answer, not about you as a person. That's all._

Comment: Ich sehe das wie @jonathan.scholbach. Ich sehe zusätzlich aber auch nicht die Notwendigkeit, Analyse durch Betrachtung zu ersetzen. Analyse drückt meiner Meinung nach eine tiefergehende Betrachtung als, als eine normale Betrachtung. Über Sprachästhetik (Vokalverteilung) würde ich hier gar nicht diskutieren.
PS: Im Deutschen wird in den meisten Fällen kein Apostroph zur Genitivbildung benötigt.

Comment: @infinitezero  Ich finde deine Analyse schlüssig und stimme deinen Betrachtungen zu. Gleichzeitig frage ich mich aber, ob nicht die Frage nach einem "deutschen" Wort für *analytics* eben doch in die Richtung geht, *Analyse* eine weniger gute Antwort zu finden (da fast das gleiche Wort wie *analytics*) als eben irgend ein anderes gebräuchliches oder noch nicht aber vielleicht bald gebräuchliches, das auf "deutscheren" Beinen steht.

Comment: Ich sehe keinen Grund ein "deutscheres" Wort zu suchen. Gerade der Bereich ist sehr international geprägt, sodass man sich nicht nur an bereits bestehenden Worten orientieren darf, sondern diese auch übernehmen kann. Das erleichtert einem auch das Lesen von Papern oder anderen Artikeln, wenn man die entsprechenden Fachworte schon kennt.

Comment: Laurentius Albertus meint: "Noua indies nascuntur vetera antiquantur et intereunt, actuosa et significatiua saepissime obliterantur, ieiuna vero et frigida emergunt et loco ipsorum reponuntur." Aber das scheinen ja einige hier nicht zu verstehen. Pauperes scolares sew sacerdotes ignorantes virtutes vocabularum.